# How can I tell what quality/bitrate the audio stream is on a YouTube video I'm watching?

Tags: bitrate, sound-quality

Main question as per title!

Also interested in whether it's always the same format of audio (compression technique etc.) or if it depends on the audio stream in the uploaded video? Also, does the quality depend on what resolution I'm watching the video in (from memory I think it does)?
Does it depend on whether I'm using the Flash / HTML5 player?

Comment: This is a technical question which is better asked on a site like Web Apps SE — http://webapps.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/youtube. The relationship of this question to the subject of "music appreciation or history" is incidental.

Comment: @RobertCartaino We do accept audio quality questions, why is this one being an exception? Audio quality, analog or digital, is as on-topic as it gets for music appreciation. It has nothing to do with "technical support". Perhaps you are not familiar with the subject? If so, you might want to restrain from unilaterally closing questions like this.

Comment: @RobertCartaino I appreciate the link to that webapps (where some similar questions have been asked, although there are many areas where SE sites overlap). I can see that this question has split opinion but I do think that at the very least the close reason needs to be refined, for the reasons mentioned by JCPedroza.

Comment: Topo morto — This is a newly-formed site and the default close reasons have not yet been customized to real-world use cases. Per JCPedoroza's comments, this question isn't really asking about auido quality or optimal bitrates or anything like that. I just felt it stepped too far towards the technical (how to interpret a file format or how to use a web site). If the folks here disagree, the question can be reopened, but thank you for being so considerate in your response.

Comment: I think this is a "Google is your friend" type question. Paste the question into Google and the first result gives the answer.

Comment: @RogerMellie you will see from that article that the author says he got results that were counter to what what Google published. So I wonder who is right. *An answer* is not *The answer*, necessarily...

Comment: http://www.h3xed.com/web-and-internet/youtube-audio-quality-bitrate-240p-360p-480p-720p-1080p

Answer (score 7):

1. Right click a youtube video in your browser
2. Click "Stats for Nerds"
3. Look for "codecs", note the last part (e.g. "Opus 250")
4. Look up the value [here](https://gist.github.com/AgentOak/34d47c65b1d28829bb17c24c04a0096f#dash-audio)

The quality of the audio does vary with (some) video resolutions.

Answer (score 0):

The Opus 251 one does have a very wide range (less than 160Kpbs), so it could really be anything and not entirely accurate. I am looking for a way to actually get the bitrate outputted, if that's even possible.